# How can I modify the EXIF orientation tag of an image?

Tags: linux, images, jpeg, exif, exiftool

I want to change the EXIF orientation tag in my JPEG images but without actual rotating of them. I want to do this to use them as a test case for an application I made.

How I can do that in Linux? Can I do it with `exiftool`? And if so, how?

Answer (score 36):

You can retrieve the existing orientation information via `exiftool` as follows:

```
exiftool -Orientation -n image.jpg
```

This will display the internal value of the orientation information held in the MIE tags.  You can return the value as an English string by omitting the `-n` flag.  You can find [additional information here](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html) regarding particular rotation/orientation values.

*Changing* the orientation data with `exiftool` can be done as follows:

```
exiftool -Orientation=1 -n image.jpg
```

Here, the orientation is set to 1, indicating **no rotation**.  These numbers are defined as per the EXIF specification; you can see what effect different rotation values have in the link above.

*(note: you must use the `-n` argument when setting orientation to indicate that the value is numeric. If you forget, exiftool will interpret the `orientation=x` number as a string and set the wrong rotation ie. `exiftool -orientation=1 image.jpg` will actually set the orientation to 3 which is 'Rotate 180')*

Comment: You can also use this format, e.g. to rotate an image 90° clockwise: `exiftool -orientation="Rotate 90 CW" image.jpg` ([source](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=7909.0))

Comment: This blog does a really good job of describing what orientation codes represent which real-world orientations: https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/31/image_rotation_exif_info/#exif-orientation-flag

Answer (score 1):

My solution was the same as @Breakthrough, but I had to put the -n before -Orientation, such as

`exiftool -n -Orientation=1 image.jpg`

Answer (score -2):

below command can be used to change orientation 
e.g exiftool -orientation="Horizontal (normal)" filename.tiff