# Is it possible to change orientation of JPG image without rotating it (and thus losing information)?

Tags: jpeg, lossless, flip

As JPG is a lossy compression, [every re-encoding losses quality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzsbjwuWYYI). Thus, 90/180/270 degree rotation is a lossy operation as well. Is it possible to **change orientation of JPG photo** by changing some of its metadata tags so that the orientation can be changed without re-encoding the photo?

Comment: When you say "change orientation" do you mean "rotate by 90/180/270", "flip" (L/R or U/D) or both? (obviously not by any angle that isn't a multiple of 90º)

Answer (score 18):

JPG can be rotated using only EXIF data, so no re-encoding is necessary.

I found this tutorial on the orientation flag - [JPEG Rotation and EXIF Orientation](https://web.archive.org/web/20201204011853/https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html)

These days, most image apps can handle this flag, many can also write it.

[Exiftool](https://exiftool.org) is a very comprehensive multi-platform solution that can handle all exif data - see [How can I modify the EXIF orientation tag of an image?](https://superuser.com/questions/435443/how-can-i-modify-the-exif-orientation-tag-of-an-image)

Comment: Thanks! I also found a [solution using ExifTool](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/104340/6546). And I also found that IrfanView can do a lossless rotation (menu Options / JPG lossless rotation), do you know if it works via EXIF as well? :-)

Comment: jpeg images can be really lossless rotated by 90 degrees (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543402/can-a-jpeg-compressed-image-be-rotated-without-a-loss-in-quality)

Comment: Besides, EXIF data does not rotate an image. It only provides a hint to renderers to perform their own rotation on display. Such a rotation is probably _worse_ than even a lossless "real" rotation performed ahead of time, for performance reasons.

Comment: @Tomas https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/104366 _IrfanView can indeed rotate JPEG images in a lossless way, and it indeed needs the JPG_TRANSFORM plugin to do that. Luckily that plugin is already included in a normal install of IrfanView. To check you have the plugin: go to Help -> Installed PlugIns and check if JPG_TRANSFORM.DLL is in the list._

Comment: Note that a lossless true rotation is only possible if the image size is a multiple of the block size in both dimensions (depending on the subsampling options used, the block size may be 8x8, 8x16, 16x8 or 16x16).

Comment: `Note that a lossless true rotation is only possible if the image size is a multiple of the block size in both dimensions` - Forsooth, IrfanView will give an error if you try to use the lossless-rotation function on images that have incompatible dimensions. Still, most unmodified images (straight from the camera, screenshot tool, etc.) will have compatible dimensions.

Comment: `jpegtran` specifically has a `-perfect` option that can be used for lossless rotation and cropping.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Why would such a rotation (on display) be "worse"? It would be a rotation on the (already decoded) bitmap it memory, no re-encoding to create loss?

Comment: @MrWhite That's a fair point